# MS Access Parent/Child Relationships

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Database design is very confusing for me. I understand the concepts, but "good design" is complicated, and I want it correct.

So I have very fundamental questions.

Question 1) If I have three tables, tbl_lenders, tbl_programs, tbl_products, is it considered ok, or good design, to link the primary key from tbl_lenders to one foreign key to each tbl_programs and tbl_products. So basically, one primary key from one table to two different tables.

Question 2) In this database is a questionnaire of sorts. I need to call a bunch of banks and inquire about the government programs they subscribe to and any in-house products they may offer. There are a bunch of Yes/No questions. I have read many of times not to use the Yes/No data-type on Access. So I created a table called tbl_options, which has a few records, of which are Yes, No and N/A. Can I make a relationship from tbl_options to multiple fields in tbl_programs (and tbl_products). So multiple relationships between the same primary key in one table to multiple foreign keys located in different but single table.[image]

[image]

Picture one is visual example of question one, where I have a one to many relationship from the primary key in tbl_lenders to one table and then to another.

The second picture is an example of the second question, where tbl_options and tbl_options_1 are the same table (just MS Access doing its thing) and its primary key is making a relationship to multiple fields in a second table.

Is this ok?

Comment: You've tagged this question for three different database. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: MS Access. I tagged it as three to get someone's attention. I figured they are all relational databases (I know, no one likes Access, lol) so I figured the basic nature of the question would apply to all three.

Comment: This is really a logical design question, and so the database is largely irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer Question 1:

When I would do logical design, I would try hard to name both ends of a relationship and see if it makes sense. For example, it looks like you have
a many-to-many relationship between LENDERS and PROGRAMS.

```
           xxxxxxx
PROGRAM >-------------------------< LENDERS
                            yyyyyy
```

So if you name each end of the relationship, you can mechanically construct two sentanecs

Each program is xxxxxx one or more lenders
Each lender is yyyyyy one or more programs

Take a look at this website for a simple example: http://www.entitymodelling.org/

Now you cannot implement a many-to-many relationship with just two tables; you have to resolve it via an intersection entity (sometimes referred to
as a bridge table). The intersection entity is usually just the primary keys of the two tables, for example

```
PROGRAM ---------< LENDERPROGRAM >--------- LENDER
```

So the long answer to your question is yes, it's a valid design, providing it makes business sense.

Comment: Thanks for your time Bob. I really appreciate it. Question 1 is more about the primary key in tbl_lenders having a one-to-many relationship to both the junction (bridge) table to the left and right of it in the picture. I'm fairly certain that this is ok, and I'm fairly certain that the second question is not ok. I just want to make sure before I go any further. Again, thank you.

Comment: For Q2, it looks like your PROGRAMS table has a column for each program or product; am I reading that right?

Comment: The programs table's intent is to hold information on government mortgage programs. So each row will be a new program: for instants, FHA - Title II, VA, USDA, Conventional, etc.... Each column provides information on the program. Minimum Down Payment, Insured Amount, Gifted Land. For questions that are Yes/No questions, I want to stay away from using the Yes/No data-type because I've read from multiple sources not to use it.

Comment: So with the reducing redundancy database rule, I created a table with a few common answers (tbl_options), such as Yes, No, N/A. I'm not sure how to build that relationship between the two tables though. Can I make a relationship for each Yes/No question from the same table to the common answers table?

Comment: OK. So then a "Yes" is indicated by a row in the lenderProgram table, is it not?

Comment: In the second picture, you'll see two tables on the left, tbl_options and tbl_options_1. That's actually one table. MS Access made two by default for whatever reason. That table has Yes, No, N/A in it. You'll notice the primary key from tbl_options has two relationships with two fields in the table to the right, tbl_programs. Both of those fields are Yes/No questions. Can I just make relationships like that and Access work properly?

Comment: I can't comment on Access; I'm just talking about relational design. But I think the Yes, No, N/A could be an attribute of the bridge table. In fact, it may be that a lack of entry in the bridge table is an implicit N/A. Lets say you have 5000 possible programs, but for a given lender, they would only answer Y or N to say 10 of them. You would only need 10 rows in the bridge table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the yes/no questions are about the programs themselves. I match the lender with the programs they offer in the bridge table, but I provide the detail about the program in the programs table. To provide that detail, there are yes/no questions that need to be answered about each program. So, I also read I want to stay away from Null values as much as possible, and that's why I don't want to leave a question without some sort of answer, whether it's yes, no or N/A. Maybe I'm making life too hard on myself. lol

Comment: Why do you need to stay away from nulls? Is this a limitation in Access?

Comment: Just stuff I've read in the past. It's not a limitation, but I think it can cause issues if migrating to a more robust system, and something about Null values not being 0 or nothing, it's considered some kind of value.

Comment: If your design is solid, NULLs are perfectly valid and you should not shy away from them. NULL's are an "absence of value", so they are not 0 ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time, Bob. Again, I appreciate it.

Comment: The comment about Yes/No (Boolean/Bit) fields being depreceated is to do with potential upsizing from Access to say MS SQL. Access allows a Null value in a bit field which many of the Enterprise databases do NOT. As long as you always have a non Null default value for a Bit field then you won't have any issues if you ever upsize.